# Can I modify this macro to run just on one column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this to find and replace values, and it works fine for the entire sheet I have open:

```
Sub replaceStringInCells()
Dim wTxt As String
Dim rTxt As String
Dim rNum As Integer
rNum = 0
For Each Row In Range("swapvalues").Rows  '<== change the wordlist Name here as required
    wTxt = Row.Cells(1).Value
    rTxt = Row.Cells(2).Value
        Selection.Replace What:=wTxt, Replacement:=rTxt, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
            rNum = rNum + 1
Next
End Sub
```

I'd like to edit it so that I runs just on Column U--instead of the full sheet.

I've seen other folks try to solve this using lines like `Set rng = Range("U:U")` but I'm not sure where to add that in the code above or if this is the best approach.

If anyone has a suggestion, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your code exactly?

Comment: Are you trying to change the range that the loop runs on, or just replace values in column U, or replace values in column U of the selected range? Can you provide same data, expected result?

Comment: The macro is finds and replaces data in a workbook. The source is [here.](https://old.reddit.com/r/excelevator/comments/5ftnha/vba_macro_replace_values_in_cells_from_list_of/) And, I'm looking for a way to make it replace data in just the U column--rather than the whole document or a selected range.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Range("U:U").Replace What:=wTxt, Replacement:=rTxt, LookAt:=xlPart
```